# gradle property and dependency resolution

Tags: gradle

I have a simple gradle question, but I can't manage do make it work.

I would like to define a dependency outside of the build.gradle file (so the end-user doesn't open it)

In gradle.properties, I wrote
myDependency=XXXX

and in the build.gradle I wront

dependency {
 compile 'goup:module'myDependency
}

But this doesn't work.
The property is never read and put in the dependency strucutre from the build.gradle.

I tried
project.properties['myDependency']
$myDependency

but none of this worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dependencies { compile "goup:module:$myDependency" }
```